# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala. I am executing below code on Spark:

```
scala>   for(line <- sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:8020/property.conf")) 
         {
            val c = line.split("=")
            SparkConf.set(c(0), c(1)) 
            //println(c(0)+" "+c(1))   //Commented
         }
```

If I remove commented part and comment `SparkConf.set(c(0), c(1))`  then it works fine and display data.

But In this case I want to set parameters to **SparkConf** at runtime.
But it throws me error that

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Please suggest me Something.

Comment: I searched on google. but not found anything specific to this. Is there any way i can serialized this

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is very important to understand about spark is that it is a distributed environment.

The name `RDD` is a short-form for `Resilient Distributed Datasets`. The items in a spark RDD are generally divided into `partitions` which are distributed on various different nodes in Spark cluster.

When you call something like `yourRdd.map(a => a.toString)`, the `map` implementation of this RDD knows that it has to first wrap this `a => a.toString` function in a closure, then serialize that closure and then send it to all the nodes which have `partitions` of this `RDD`. The actual computation of result takes place on those nodes.

So... when you are dealing with `RDD`'s make sure that you don't confuse/mix distribution aware `RDD` api with normal Scala api.

The recommended way to write you piece of code will be,

```
val yourRdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:8020/property.conf")) 

yourRdd.foreach(line =>
  val c = line.split("=")
  println(c(0) + " " + c(1))
)
```

Here in your `SparkConf.set(c(0), c(1))` line, `SparkConf` is a `class` and you normally can not serialize `classes`. Neither can you call member function `set` on `class SparkConf`. You need to create instances of `classes`. Also `SparkConf` happens to be a class which does not implement the serializable interface and hence even the instances of `SparkConf` are not serializable.

Normally you should not be using a spark RDD to create your `SparkConf` as RDD will not exist without a `SparkContext` which in turn needs a `SparkConf` to be initialized.

But for this case lets say you needed to do just that... then you first have a get a normal scala list from your RDD then use that to create your SparkConf.

```
val mySparkConf = new SparkConf()

val yourRdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:8020/property.conf")) 

val yourList = yourRdd.foreach(line =>
  val c = line.split("=")
).collect.toList

yourList.foreach(c => mySparkConf.set(c(0), c(1)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for information. But when I am writing SparkConf.set(c(0), c(1)) inside forech. then it throws me error that org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: As I said... the functions need to be serialise before sending them to corresponding nodes. And thus functions should not have anything that is can not be serialized and `SparkConf` just happens to be one of such thing.